# How do I reset .htaccess username and password for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, phpmyadmin, apache2

I recently set up the .htaccess security for logging into phpMyAdmin. Unfortunately I forgot my password or the username. How do I reset both?

I tried
`sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd root` and that let me enter a new password, however it did not register when I am trying to log in, in the browser alert prompt.

I am using apache2 as my webserver.

Thanks!

Comment: By ".htaccess security" do you mean HTTP Authentication? To "reset" it you need to follow the exact same process you used to set it up in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible that when you first configured the security, instead of creating a `.htaccess` file that you instead changed the phpMyAdmin auth_type to 'http'? There are several phpMyAdmin authentication types, cookie, http, and config are most common. The http type uses a standard browser login popup that is the same as the one used by an .htaccess authentication. Can you look in your phpMyAdmin configuration (config.inc.php) and tell us the auth_type setting?